# Yii php application breaks processing csv file after 30 seconds

Tags: php, csv, yii

I have a php application, written using Yii framework.

The controller that actually is giving me an issue, get a csv file, open it to read the content and add/update a database record for each csv file line.

```
public function actionGetCSVArticleData(){
    try {
        $file = fopen("C:\\wamp\\www\\ps\\articoli.csv","r");
        $result ="";
        $i=0;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE)
        {
            $result[$i++]=  $data;
        }

        for($j=1;$j<count($result);$j++){
            for($k=0;$k<count($result[$j]);$k++){
                $tempData = $result[$j];
                $articleMgmt = new ArticleMgmt();

                if(isset($tempData[0]) && isset($tempData[3])) {
                    $articleMgmt->code=trim($tempData[0]);
                    $articleMgmt->customer_code=trim($tempData[3]);
                } else {
                    $articleMgmt->code=null;
                }

                if($articleMgmt->code!=null){
                    $tCode = $this->isArticleExist($articleMgmt->code, $articleMgmt->customer_code);

                    if($tCode !=-1){
                        $updateArticle = ArticleMgmt::model()->findByPk($tCode);
                        $this->updateArticle($updateArticle,$tempData);
                    }else{
                        $this->updateArticle($articleMgmt,$tempData);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($file);

        $count = ArticleMgmt::model()->count();
        $articleData = ArticleMgmt::model()->findAll();
        $result = array('data' => $articleData, 'total' => $count);

        echo CJSON::encode($result);
    } catch(Exception $e){
        echo CJSON::encode(array("success" => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage()));
    }
}
```

The problem is that after 30 seconds the call to the controller method is cancelled and it does not process the whole file but only the first part. Consider that I have about 40.000 lines in the file and it breaks after about 7800.
[image: chrome consolle error]
The strange thing is that I have checked and modified the php.ini without any result:

```
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 120
memory_limit = 256 Mb
```

[image]
I don't understand where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure
you edited correct php.ini,
and in phpinfo you have 
`max_execution_time=600`
Have you restarted apache after changing?

Comment: Yes; I restarted apache more then one time after each php.ini change and also checked with phpinfo() and I currently see the changed values.
You can see the capture in my edited question

Comment: I know it maybe stupid but have you tried putting in php code
`set_time_limit(120);`

Comment: in apache error log there is nothing related to this issue; for set_time_limit in php I will try..... do I have to set it inside the controller method?

Comment: I inserted set_time_limit(120); as first line of actionGetCSVArticleData function but also in this way, after 30 sec, it breaks method execution

Comment: I assumed that you already turned on debug mode in yii and it didn't show the problem and 
`echo ini_get('max_execution_time'); `
is displaying 120

Comment: maybe it's a problem with ajax check if you have maybe set timeout in you ajax request

Comment: have you tried to run this link not as ajax request (open this link in new tab)? This will decide if it is problem with javascript or php.